# How to annotate text in d3

Tags: d3.js

I have data in following format:

```
{'topics': [ ['word1','word2','word3'...],
['word11','word21','word31'...],..['word31','word22','word33'...]],
 "text":
[{"word1":1,"weight":22},{"word2":4,"weight":2}....}] }
```

So, basically, these are data from topic models and I am trying to generate plots like in this paper http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~blei/papers/Blei2012.pdf (page 2)

So, topics consists of k topics and top words in each topic.
Whereas "text" contains the alphabet in a document and then next to it . So for example : {"word1":1,"weight":22} says "word1" in this document is allocated to topic1 and has a weight 22..
What I want is to annotate each word in this document by a color ?
Is there a way to do this in d3? (I am new in d3)

[image]

Comment: do you have any d3 code so far?

Comment: @deweyredman Actually no.. I know, this is a bad practise here. I am just so new in d3 (and javascript).. I am looking into documentation as of now.. but cant seem to find text annotation..

Comment: highlighting the text with certain colors is pretty straightforward.  Do you want to do exactly what the picture you have represents?

Comment: You would need to identify each word in the document and wrap it in a `span` element or something like that. It doesn't sounds like D3 would be the right tool for the job as this is more about modifying existing content with search-type operations that generating data-driven content.

Comment: @deweyredman Yeah.. actually exactly that..

Answer (score 1):

You can do this a number of ways (thanks for the edit to your post, it made it more clear, by the way):

it sounds like [ordinal scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales) are probably what you are looking for, or you could always do an explicit function based on the value of the data.